# Store/retrieve child-parent relationship with JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON structure (including POCO classes) with child-objects arrays like this:

```
    "Object": [
    {
        "Name": "TestA",
        "ChildObjects": [
        {
            "Name": "TestB"
            "ChildObjects": [
                {
                    "Name": "TestC"
                    ...
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

When deserializing, I would like to keep a reference to the parent
object I've just created.

**But I must get this reference before populating the child-object.(On the moment that I populate the child-object I must have the parent-object structure/reference accessible)**.

I've tried using a custom JsonConverter, but
I could not find a way to store or retrieve this relationship.

Comment: Did you try setting the [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm) setting to `Objects`?  If you do that, you should not need a converter; the references will be preserved in the JSON by means of special `$id` and `$ref` meta properties.

Comment: @BrianRogers, I've thinked about adding a "Parent Object" property to the "Object Class". This way I would be able to get a reference to the parent. Does this reference stuff you just told fits for this use? (If it can work as a reference to the parent node on the JSON file)

Comment: Yes, your child object can have a reference to the parent and vice versa, and it should work if you use that setting both when serializing and deserializing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share (ideally simplified) versions of what your types look like -- i.e. a [mcve]?  I'm confused as to what types correspond to the JSON above, and which need a parent during creation.

Comment: @dbc, it's done

Comment: @BrianRogers, your solution seems to be acceptible, but I should have the parent reference before actually populating the child-object

Comment: @RicardoReis - is the root `Object` of the same type as the items in the `ChildObjects` items?

Comment: @dbc, yes, it is

Answer (score 7):

Rather than defining this as a serialization problem (how to serialize and deserialize a back-reference to a parent), it might make sense to define this as a class design problem, namely

> *Given a hierarchy of parents and children, how to ensure that child back-references to parents are **automatically** set correctly when adding them to their parents*?

Once the problem is defined in this way and solved, correctness should be assured both during deserialization and during programmatic data creation, since the parent back-reference would never need to be serialized or deserialized.

One way to accomplish this would be to define a custom subclass of [`Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx) that automatically sets and clears parent back references.

First, define the following interface and collection:

```
public interface IHasParent<TParent> where TParent : class
{
    TParent Parent { get; }

    void OnParentChanging(TParent newParent);
}

public class ChildCollection<TParent, TChild> : Collection<TChild>
    where TChild : IHasParent<TParent>
    where TParent : class
{
    readonly TParent parent;

    public ChildCollection(TParent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            if (item != null)
                item.OnParentChanging(null);
        }
        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, TChild item)
    {
        if (item != null)
            item.OnParentChanging(parent);
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        var item = this[index];
        if (item != null)
            item.OnParentChanging(null);
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, TChild item)
    {
        var oldItem = this[index];
        if (oldItem != null)
            oldItem.OnParentChanging(null);
        if (item != null)
            item.OnParentChanging(parent);
        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Then define your `MyObject` and `RootObject` types as follows:

```
public class MyObject : IHasParent<MyObject>
{
    readonly ChildCollection<MyObject, MyObject> childObjects;

    public MyObject() { this.childObjects = new ChildCollection<MyObject, MyObject>(this); }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<MyObject> ChildObjects { get { return childObjects; } }

    #region IHasParent<MyObject> Members

    [JsonIgnore]
    public MyObject Parent { get; private set; }

    public void OnParentChanging(MyObject newParent)
    {
        Parent = newParent;
    }

    #endregion

    // Added to suppress serialization of empty ChildObjects collections to JSON.
    public bool ShouldSerializeChildObjects() { return childObjects.Count > 0; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject() { this.Object = new List<MyObject>(); }

    public List<MyObject> Object { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- The collection `IList<MyObject> ChildObjects` in `MyObject` is get-only.  Json.NET (and `XmlSerializer` for that matter) can successfully deserialize a get-only, pre-allocated collection.
- The method `ShouldSerializeChildObjects()` is optional and prevents serialization of empty `ChildObjects []` array values.
- Since [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) is itself a subclass of `Collection<T>`, you could chose it as the base class for `ChildCollection<TParent, TChild>` if you require notifications when items are added or removed.
- The `Parent` property is marked with [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) to prevent its serialization.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uR7kwf) including some basic unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

For clearer understanding dbc's answer let me simplify it.

Let's take example of setting parent for `RootObject`'s item called `MyObject`:

```
{
    "Object":[
        {
            "Name": "TestA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Define collection:

```
public class Items : Collection<MyObject>
{
    private RootObject Owner;

    public Items(RootObject owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, MyObject item)
    {
        item.Parent = Owner;
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Define `MyObject` and `RootObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public RootObject Parent { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject() { ChildObjects = new Items(this); }

    public Items ChildObjects { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You needn't JsonConverter.

You can create POCO classes that represent your json, as given below:

```
    public class OstacolisRuntime
    {
        public int CodiceOstacolo { get; set; }
        public int TipoOstacolo { get; set; }
        public int Tipologia { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public double PosizioneX { get; set; }
        public double PosizioneY { get; set; }
        public double PosizioneZ { get; set; }
        public double AngoloX { get; set; }
        public double AngoloY { get; set; }
        public double AngoloZ { get; set; }
        public double ScalaX { get; set; }
        public double ScalaY { get; set; }
        public double ScalaZ { get; set; }
        public List<SubOggetto> SubOggettos { get; set; } //sub
    }




    public class SubOggetto
    {
        public string Immagine { get; set; }
        public int Tipologia { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public double PosizioneX { get; set; }
        public double PosizioneY { get; set; }
        public double PosizioneZ { get; set; }
        public double AngoloX { get; set; }
        public double AngoloY { get; set; }
        public double AngoloZ { get; set; }
        public double ScalaX { get; set; }
        public double ScalaY { get; set; }
        public double ScalaZ { get; set; }
        public List<SubOggetto> SubOggettos { get; set; } //recursive relashioship
    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<OstacolisRuntime> OstacolisRuntime { get; set; }
    }
```

Deserialize you json:

```
  var o= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

You can check  [complete source code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UI31WN)

Comment: M. Hassan. I already have these classes. I must find a way to obtain this relationship when deserializing. The child node must be able to know the parent node on deserialization.