# c#/json.net deserialize child with data from parent

Tags: json.net, deserialization

```
    class Item
    {
    public string Id;
    public List<Item> Children;
    }
```

json

```
    {
        "Id" : "/parent",
        "Children" : [
        {
            "Id" : "/child1"
        }
        ]
    }
```

I have class for creating nested items.
How would I have a child item access the parent's Id field during/after deserialization of the child? Or is there a way to send the parent Id field when the child is to be created?

Example:
Parent Id "/parent"
Child Id "/child1"
I want the child Id "/parent/child1"

For reasons, I cannot use '[OnDeserialized]' after the parent is finished to loop children and change Id. Nor do I have access to change the json files themselves.

Comment: A JSON object is defined by the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) to be an *an **unordered** set of name/value pairs* so in general there;s  no reason to assume that the `"Id"` property will be encountered before the `"Children"` property.  Perhaps for that reason, Json.NET doesn't provide access to the parent while deserializing the child.

Comment: There are some workarounds however.  See e.g. [Store/retrieve child-parent relationship with JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46774119) or [How can I deserialize instances of a type that has read-only back-references to some container type also being deserialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56316631).  Do either of those approaches work for you?

Comment: Alternatively you could do everything in an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback.  We need to see a [mcve] to get an idea of what might work best.